# Passing a Backbone model from a collection to a new view keeps the collection in memory

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a CompositeView that shows a list of models that I requested from a server, something like (in CoffeeScript):

```
class List.Stories extends Marionette.CompositeView
    template: "stories-list-body"
    itemView: List.Story
    itemViewContainer: "#stories-list"

class List.Story extends Marionette.ItemView
    template: "stories-list-story"
    triggers:
        "click .js-show-button": "show:button:clicked"
```

The views are correctly created passing the collection as an argument for the constructor, I can see the elements and when I click on the button it triggers the appropriate event and it's handled. The thing is, when the handler creates a new view showing the model and closes the old one, the collection is still referenced in `model.collection` taking up some memory.

What would be the correct way to eliminate this reference? Simply using `delete model.collection` in the handler before replacing the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like

```
var model = myCollection.remove(viewModel, { silent: true })

// create new view using `model`
```

In the example above, `viewModel` would refer to the view's model (so it would be `this.model` from within the view).

By removing the model from the collection, it should be garbage collected (assuming it's not referenced anywhere else...).

Comment: I added the code in a modified version of `view.close` method before calling the original close. It removes all models from the collection leaving a collection with no elements, but the collection is still there. It's not referenced by the model as before so I will have to look where it is referenced (DevTools is a little bit cryptic)

Comment: Check `on` event listeners to see if there isn't a reference to the collection in one of them by any chance...

Comment: I don't use any `on`, only `listenTo` to ensure that Marionette/Backbone will clean up for me.

Comment: I think I found the leak. Removing the models as you suggested leaves only references by the system (GC, bound_this, etc) and the original composite view that is referenced only by the system, so my guess is that Chrome is not handling well those references.

Answer (score 0):

If it all happens within same controller, i.e. the controller is still open and will be responsible for the event and no Application.vent will be triggered, I think this situation is acceptable if memory leak won't be big. The reason is the controller will be finally closed so no need in a hurry.

If App level vent/request/command will be triggered, you need to take it seriously. Assume you have such code in controller:

```
@listenTo storiesView, 'itemview:show:button:clicked', (itemView) ->
  App.vent.trigger 'show:another:view:with:this:model', itemView.model
```

Stop here. The model is the old model and won't be garbage collected.

I will use below code instead:

```
@listenTo storiesView, 'itemview:show:button:clicked', (itemView) ->
  model = _.clone itemView.model
  App.vent.trigger 'show:another:view:with:this:model', model
```

The new model is a totally new object and then has nothing related to current view/model/controller.

Comment: I'm ok with reusing the model, I think it's even better as you don't have to allocate new memory. The problem is the collection attribute inside the model.